# how to use DESTDIR for ninja build with c++

Tags: cmake, debian, gnu-make, ninja

I do see a similar question here: [ninja appends its default installation path to my DESTDIR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66817257/ninja-appends-its-default-installation-path-to-my-destdir)

But this time the problem is I am not using meson. I am working with cmake for c++ project,
I used to use:

```
$(MAKE) install DESTDIR=
```

to skip DESTDIR earlier but using

```
DESTDIR= ninja install
```

will do nothing as it just prefixes existing path instead of changing it effectively, the motive is to skip debian/tmp based jailbreak for building and installing cmake external project.

Any suggestions welcome as well!

Comment: "it just prefixes existing path instead of changing it effectively" - This is how `DESTDIR` is expected to work with `make`. `DESTDIR` does NOT replace installation prefix, it prepends the prefix.